# Как передать ключ элемента в вложенный массив при onMouseEnter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/ChampionTommy/test/draft/strange-firefly?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2Fheader%2FNavigate.jsx&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A7%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A10%2C%22startColumn%22%3A7%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A10%7D%5D&workspace=%257B%2522activeFileId%2522%253A%2522clbzhgii300087ogpct01gcde%2522%252C%2522openFiles%2522%253A%255B%2522%252Fsrc%252Fcomponents%252Fheader%252FNavigatePopup.jsx%2522%252C%2522%252Fsrc%252Fcomponents%252Fheader%252FNavigate.jsx%2522%252C%2522%252Fsrc%252Fcomponents%252Fheader%252FNavigateLink.jsx%2522%255D%252C%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522gitSidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522COMMIT%2522%252C%2522spaces%2522%253A%257B%2522clbzhgk8a001320681mfm8f15%2522%253A%257B%2522key%2522%253A%2522clbzhgk8a001320681mfm8f15%2522%252C%2522name%2522%253A%2522Default%2522%252C%2522devtools%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522key%2522%253A%2522clbzhgk8b00142068s0cyd2fo%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PROJECT_SETUP%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PREVIEW%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522clbzhh8yn00z62068unlmcqqo%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522clbzhh61r00w12068ss1l150y%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522currentSpace%2522%253A%2522clbzhgk8a001320681mfm8f15%2522%252C%2522spacesOrder%2522%253A%255B%2522clbzhgk8a001320681mfm8f15%2522%255D%257D)

Здравствуйте, изучаю `js + react` и собственно такая проблема... Хотел сделать `dropdown`-menu из объекта (типо mockdata) и не могу понять, как правильно отобразить список `links` по `key` родительского элемента.

```
{randomLinks.Navigate.map((nav_links, index) => {
  const keys = index;
  console.log(keys);
  return (
    <>
      <NavigateLink
        key={keys}
        data={nav_links.category}
        hoverMenu={hoverMenu}
        onMouseEnter={handeChangeState}
        onMouseLeave={handleChangeStateOver}
      />
      {hoverMenu && (
        <div
          key={index}
          className={`w-full mt-0 shadow-lg bg-white absolute`}
          onMouseLeave={() => setHoverMenu(false)}
          onMouseOver={() => setHoverMenu(true)}
        >
          {randomLinks.Navigate[keys].links.map((i) => {
            return <NavigatePopup key={index} data={i} />;
          })}
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
})}
```

*т.е я навожу на элемент **parent** и он в свою очередь выдает мне key, который будет использоваться во вложенном **child**. Тем самым я получу элементы массивов, а сейчас у меня просто все подряд дропается...*

На данный момент просто себя запутал...

Comment: Выложите сюда части тех компонентов, в которых возникла проблема. Выискивать по всему коду, что же у вас там работает не так, как вы ожидаете, сложно. А песочница, это хорошо.

Comment: Добавил кусок кода, грубо говоря в "randomLinks.Navigate[keys]" в скобках keys должен быть как раз ключ категории переданный в onMouseEnter, чтоб вывести  массив ссылок, если ввести например 0 или 1, то в зависимости от ключа выпадет меню из двух или 6-ти ссылок

Comment: Сделай работающий тестовый пример. На нем можно будет показать варианты решений...

Comment: Так он работающий, открываешь codesandbox и на весь экран выводишь ссылку и там полностью рабочий ховер с элементами, единственно то, что долго обрабатываются img почему-то, в целом там все норм.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вам надо изменить условия отображения дочерних элементов.

Для этого надо создать переменную состояния, в которую будем записывать индекс элемента, на который мышка наведена и удалять тогда, когда мышка будет убрана.

Условие отображения меняем с `hoverMenu &&` на `howId === index &&`

```
const [howId, setHowId] = useState(null); // Хранит Index элемента

{randomLinks.Navigate.map((nav_links, index) => {
  const keys = index;
  console.log(keys);
  return (
    <>
      <NavigateLink
        key={keys}
        data={nav_links.category}
        hoverMenu={hoverMenu}
        onMouseEnter={(e) => {
          handeChangeState(e);
          setHowId(index); // При наведении записываем значение
        }}
        onMouseLeave={(e) => {
          handleChangeStateOver(e);
          setHowId(null); // Зануляем значение
        }}
      />

      {howId === index && (
        <div
          key={index}
          className={`w-full mt-0 shadow-lg bg-white absolute`}
          onMouseLeave={() => setHoverMenu(false)}
          onMouseOver={() => setHoverMenu(true)}
        >
          {randomLinks.Navigate[keys].links.map((i) => {
            return <NavigatePopup key={index} data={i} />;
          })}
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
})}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, хоть примерно буду знать как правильно делать выборку <3